# Elasticsarch: fuzziness in match_phrase

Tags: elasticsearch, match-phrase

I need to make a *full text query* to *match phrase* with several words, with defined `slop`. But text may have misspellings, hence I need `fuzziness` as well.

- I may use `match_phrase` with `slop`, then I lose `fuzziness`
- I may use `match` with `fuzziness` with `operator: "and"`, then I lose `slop`
- I may use `span_near` then I lose *full text query*, it would be *term query*

Do you have any suggestions to perform fuzzy match phrase?